# Calculate rotation of position relative to my position

Tags: javascript, math, rotation, direction, altv

I have a position somewhere on my map (in GTAV). In JavaScript it could be something like:`let targetPos = {x: 1200, y: 653, z: 250};` and I have my position which changes every time I walk or rotate. Now what I want is to get the direction of the targetPos whenever I rotate or walk. Not the function but the math solution. Currently I'm using `var angle = Math.atan2(pos1.y - pos2.y, pos1.x - pos2.x) * (180 / Math.PI);` which is not working as intended. It gives me the angle in degree but not when I rotate myself or when I walk around it. In short: I want the direction of a position relative to my position. So I can rotate a circle to show in the target direction.

Here is what I have:

- The player position (x, y, z), rotation (x, y, z) and heading (yaw)
- The target position

As you can see in the horrible image, the circle doesn't show in the direction of the target when the player rotates[image]

I hope you know what I mean

Comment: The equation you've used to calculate the angle is correct. When you want the result be relative to the rotation of the start point, you simply subtract the calculated angle from the rotation angle.

Comment: @Teemu when i try to subtract it, it doesn't work either with 'angle - myheading'

Comment: Please show the related code, maybe we can apply the solution to it.

Comment: it would be Alt:V(GTAV) related but here: `let deg = aTd-native.getEntityHeading(p.scriptID);` where getEntityHeading puts out the YAW of the player

Comment: From the image, 173 degrees seems reasonable, for something almost directly behind you. What's the problem? Do you want the red arc to be *below* the green circle?

Comment: No, I am the green Circle. The red 1/4 circle is the target position. and you can see myself in the image on the left side and i am not looking into the direction of the target which is marked with the X. The red arc is showing in the wrong direction and doesnt move when i rotate myself. So it isn‘t reasonable because it is showing completely in the wrong direction.

Comment: I will ask again: is 173 correct, and do you want the red arc to be *below* the green circle?

Comment: i will reply again: no 173 is still not correct as i said.  am the green Circle. The red 1/4 circle is the target position. and you can see myself in the image on the left side and i am not looking into the direction of the target which is marked with the X. The red arc is showing in the wrong direction and doesnt move when i rotate myself. So it isn‘t reasonable because it is showing completely in the wrong direction.

Comment: That is the first time you said that 173 is not correct, I can only guess that you want the red arc to be below the green circle and that the target coordinates are the numbers you gave in the question, and I still don't know the coordinates of the character, nor the yaw of the character, nor what you think the output ought to be. I want to help you, but you are fixated on the wrong things.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/tKaosxP.png Why do you want to know the coordinates of the player? there a more than 100 Trillion because the player can move and rotate. And why do you need the YAW? i just asked for the mathematical solution i think you didnt read the messages i wrote because i said twice the same thing you need to know. So last time: the Green circle is the player and the red arc is the Position i want to show relative on the radar of the player. The arc is facing the wrong direction because the target is behind the player and the arc is facing up instead of down as you can see

Comment: I cannot help you.